# while uploading file to android market error

Tags: android

When i am uploading my application in android market it showing below error

> The file is invalid:ERROR:dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found.

When I unzip the .apk file, the AndoridManifest.xml file is there.

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you double check spelling?  It's misspelled in your post.

Comment: sorry i am poor in english. where i am misspelled

Comment: "AndoridManifest.xml" should be "AndroidManifest.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following points are need to be taken care of while uploading file on android market

1. "android:versionCode" attribute from AndroidManifest.xml is proper.
2. "android:versionName" attribute from AndroidManifest.xml is proper.
3. The package name is very unique,. Because all the apps on android market are separated by the package.

see all this is in place....

Comment: Thankq for your reply

 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0"
packagename  i am using com.fitzegineering.TeslaCalculator

i following everything what u specified but what's the problem