# The file is invalid:ERROR:dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've faced this problem when I'm trying to upload my android application on Android market. I've visited [this question and answer of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130420/while-uploading-file-to-android-market-error) and I believe that my AndroidManifest.xml is in apk file when I export and all content of this xml file are correct for sure as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.cfdocumentation"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/coldfusion_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Detail" />
        <activity android:name=".related" />
        <activity android:name=".Lists" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />     
</manifest>
```

Please help me how come I faced this error message of android market when I'm trying to upload.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project before exporting it?

Comment: yap, sure. I did it. Anything solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. It's because of I've uploaded apk to Market with ultersurf proxy. Because Android market block our country's IP.

Comment: Please explain if you used another proxy or how you solved it, so others could solve it if they have the same problem. Glad you fixed.

Comment: I've uploaded my apk file to Android Market with yourfreedom proxy instead of ultersurf.

Answer (score -1):

Faced this problem minutes ago. My Manifest was correct and I kept getting this Error.
This worked for me:

Open the Manifest file in Eclipse, go to the end of the file I found lots of " " characters follow by the tag . Delete the " " characters and save.

Then just export it from Eclipse and upload it to Google Play. And it WORKS.