# ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

When I try to upload an application to Android Play store I get the following error:

```
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

Steps that I took:

- new HDD, install clean jre, jdk
- download Android eclipse bundle - latest version today
- make a new project, sample. simple hello world
- sign it with the wizard, create a certificate etc.
- try to upload it on the market...=ERROR!

I tried many combinations, different eclipse versions. Even to sign it manually. It doesn't work.
If I try to run `aapt dump badging` I get the same error.

Comment: nope. there's no proxy involved

Comment: how signature your application ?

Comment: can you put your manifest file here ?

Comment: it's sample project from android. like I said, ...it doesnt even have internet requirements.

Comment: Can you upload the .apk package?

Comment: Not using com.example namespace for the package name?

Comment: Does it have a clean build and run in your device without signing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686427/the-file-is-invaliderrordump-failed-because-no-androidmanifest-xml-found

Comment: Have you checked the max filesize?

Comment: @shoerat no, i don't use that package name.

Comment: @AlejandroColorado yes, it runs

Comment: @randomizer what max filesize? it's the sample hello world project 200kb....

Comment: @randomizer i didn't even edited the manifest. like I said, it's sample hello world project.

Comment: In my case i had mistakenly renamed app-release.aab to  app-releaseaab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- compile it & export the project under Linux (eclipse)
- switch to InteliJ Studio (**recommended**)

It seems that from time to time there is a problem with eclipse under Windows 7,8.

Answer (score 41):

Just write in the terminal

```
flutter clean
```

And then

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: And then `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 19):

Just delete `app.apk` file from: `/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk`.
Visual Studio will create a new *correct* `app.apk` file.

Answer (score 7):

I dont know o 'why' of this.
I faced this problem using Visual Studio Code in a Flutter project and Im posting my solution because it can help others.
I just run 'Flutter Clean Project' and then I run the project.
All works again!

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was with the filename: I accidentally (subconsciously) renamed it to **.apk**, when it should be **.aab**

Answer (score 3):

> following points are need to be taken care of while uploading file on
>   android market
>
> "android:versionCode" attribute from AndroidManifest.xml is proper.
>   "android:versionName" attribute from AndroidManifest.xml is proper.
>   The package name is very unique,. Because all the apps on android market are separated by the package.
>
> see all this is in place....

taken from [while uploading file to android market error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130420/while-uploading-file-to-android-market-error)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue suddenly as well,

my solution was

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
```

and it started working again

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION #1: Slow down an re-read every step. ([Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup)).**

> Basic Setup for Signing.
>
> Before you begin, make sure that the Keytool utility and Jarsigner
>   utility are available to the SDK build tools. Both of these tools are
>   available in the JDK. In most cases, you can tell the SDK build tools
>   how to find these utilities by setting your JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable so it references a suitable JDK. Alternatively, you can add
>   the JDK version of Keytool and Jarsigner to your PATH variable.
>
> ...
>
> Eclipse Users
>
> If you are developing in Eclipse/ADT (and have set up Keytool and
>   Jarsigner as described above in Basic Setup for Signing), signing in
>   debug mode is enabled by default. When you run or debug your
>   application, ADT signs the .apk file with the debug certificate, runs
>   zipalign on the package, then installs it on the selected emulator or
>   connected device. No specific action on your part is needed, provided
>   ADT has access to Keytool.

**OPTION #2: Test the features required by your application with an unsigned '.apk'. ([Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing)).**

> You can use the aapt tool, included in the Android SDK, to determine
>   how Google Play will filter your application, based on its declared
>   features and permissions. To do so, run aapt with the dump badging
>   command. This causes aapt to parse your application's manifest and
>   apply the same rules as used by Google Play to determine the features
>   that your application requires.
>
> To use the tool, follow these steps:
>
> First, build and export your application as an unsigned .apk. If you
>   are developing in Eclipse with ADT, right-click the project and select
>   Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package. Select a
>   destination filename and path and click OK. Next, locate the aapt
>   tool, if it is not already in your PATH. If you are using SDK Tools r8
>   or higher, you can find aapt in the /platform-tools/ directory.
>   Note: You must use the version of aapt that is provided for the latest
>   Platform-Tools component available. If you do not have the latest
>   Platform-Tools component, download it using the Android SDK Manager.
>
> Run aapt using this syntax:
>
> ```
> $ aapt dump badging <path_to_exported_.apk>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VScode.

What happened:
After dart update, there was a permission error on flutter.bat

Solution:

1. Locate flutter.bat and give Full controll.
2. Open a cmd with Admin privileges, locate the folder that you are doing the development.
3. use 'FLutter clean' command (do not use vscode Terminal)
4. rerun app using 'Run without debug'

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter clean && flutter run
```

also works

Answer (score 1):

run flutter clean then flutter pub get. Then run your application, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Error while run xamarin.uitest on using android sdk build tools 29.
Problem solved by changing android sdk build tools to 28.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and solved by deleting all folders containing apk files in the location -
D:\FLUTTER\MY PROJECTS\SAMPLE\myapp\build\app\outputs.
if any folder is found access denied then force delete the folder or restart your system and try deleting the folder, then rebuild the app. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory `build/app/outputs/apk/debug` , and the directory `build/app/outputs/apk/flutter-apk` . Erase the present files, once the compilation has run these files will rebuild and the error will disappear!