# Uploading App to PlayStore failed

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

When am trying to upload the signed apk to PlayStore, I am getting following error :

Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'.
 Error output: Failed to run aapt dump badging
Could not find entry resources.arsc
Zip: Could not find entry AndroidManifest 
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest found

My manifest file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"  >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo" 
    android:debuggable="false">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.aa.xx"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.aa.bb"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

      <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application></manifest>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: I hope you also have the manifest colsing tag `</manifest>`

Comment: How did you create the APK?

Comment: I created signed apk using right click Project ->Android Tools -> Export Signed Application. I tried other ways too but am still getting the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590629/error-dump-failed-because-no-androidmanifest-xml-found)

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your replies. I was able to upload the App.

For people who might get similar issue here is the solution :

I just changed the package name from com.example.aa to com.zz.aa and the problem was resolved.
So i advise not to keep example in package name.

Comment: is androidmenifest.xml file available at bin folder ? If not then paste it there and then create apk

Comment: You didn't use your own package name? o_o