# How to generate App Bundle from Xamarin Android (that could be uploaded to Google Play Store)?

Tags: android, xamarin, bundle, android-app-bundle

I have to publish a Xamarin Android app on Google Play under .aab (Android App Bundle)format.
However, Google throws the following error when I tried to upload the app bundle

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging: 
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

The .aab file was generated using the msbuild tool introduced in this tutorial espisode of
[The Xamarin Show](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Android-App-Bundles-101--The-Xamarin-Show)

It did not work either when I manually put the AndroidManifest.xml inside the .aab file with winrar and signed it again with jarsigner. It also does not for the sample Xamarin Project generated by Visual Studio.

Here is the folder structure of the AAB file unzipped, AndroidManifest.xml is under /base/manifest

```
├───base
│   ├───assets
│   ├───dex
│   ├───lib
│   ├───manifest
│   │   └───AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├───res
│   └───root
│       ├───assemblies
│       ├───com
│       ├───error_prone
│       ├───fabric
│       ├───HACKED-META-INF
│       │   └───services
│       ├───jsr305_annotations
│       └───third_party
│
└───META-INF
```

Comment: Great question, I’m curious too. Is there a reason you can’t use APK for now?

Comment: Thanks, APK works fine. It's just that google complains (and my customer) everytime I upload it. But it's true that with an APK we're not providing the best possible for end user.

Comment: Open the .AAB with a zip tool and let me know if you are any file called AndroidManifest.xml in it and where.

Comment: @Pierre: I edited my post, please see the folder structure there

Comment: Looks fine. Try to generate the APKs locally using bundletool. If this works without warning or error message, then you may want to reach out to the Play developer support.

Comment: @kangl Hi , having a check with this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590629/error-dump-failed-because-no-androidmanifest-xml-found) , maybe helpful .

Comment: In Visual Studio 16.4, you can now use the "Archive" flow to create an App Bundle within a `Release` configuration and `PackageFormat` set to `bundle`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.1#ide-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format